# Cron job - need script to start VPN if not already running for job

Tags: network-manager, vpn, cron, nmcli, openconnect

I have mirror repos that I use as reference for multiple builds throughout the day. I would like to have a cron job that runs every night and does a repo sync for each of my repos.  MY problem is some of the repos require the VPN to be active - and I dont want to leave the VPN active if it wasn't already active.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and I've installed network-manager-openconnect-gnome and have my VPN configured with credentials remembered. I have NetworkManager and nmcli version 1.10.6.
I can start the connection with

```
nmcli con up <connection name>
```

but I dont know how to determine the VPN state before I turn it on.

---

with the accepted solution, I now have:

```
#! /bin/bash

connection="<connection name>"

vpn_active=$(nmcli con show --active | grep "${connection}")

if [[ $vpn_active ]] ; then
    echo "VPN is active"
else
    echo "VPN is not active"
    nmcli con up "${connection}"
fi

pushd ~/disc2/repo.cache/

for dir in * ; do

    if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
        cd $dir
        pwd;
        repo sync;
        cd ..
    fi
done

popd

if [[ ! $vpn_active ]] ; then
    echo "stopping vpn"
    nmcli con down "${connection}"
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Gnome's [nmcli](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmcli.html) website:

```
$ nmcli con show --active
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE             DEVICE  
TELUS1213-5G        a857583c-3f2a-4399-9fc6-3df74b0509f0  802-11-wireless  wlp60s0 
Wired connection 1  f1d049d0-ad20-3201-ac70-5cb8cc06a6e5  802-3-ethernet   enp59s0
```

To test if a specific connection is active use:

```
nmcli con show --active <connection_name>
```

Comment: Thanks - I was finding hits for 'status' instead of 'show'.  With this, I can now:

`#! /bin/bash

connection="<connection name>"

vpn_active=$(nmcli con show --active | grep "${connection}")

if [[ $vpn_active ]] ; then
 echo "VPN is active"
else
 echo "VPN is not active"
fi`

Comment: Great. Afer you get it working don't forget to click check mark beside this answer if it helped. That let's other users know what to do. You can also write your own answer and accept it by clicking check mark.